# SQL to get days elapsed between rows, with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

ENVIRONMENT: SQL Azure - so some exotic functions are somewhat limited.

I have a table that records logistics events on an asset, and from that table, I'd like to calculate the number of days that an asset has been at a facility. See the table example below:

```
AssetID LocationID SublocationID MoveDate
CAR1    LOC1       SUB1          1/1/2015 01:01:01
CAR1    LOC1       SUB2          1/3/2015 03:03:03
CAR1    LOC1       SUB1          1/4/2015 04:04:04
CAR1    LOC99      SUB99         1/5/2015 05:05:05
CAR1    LOC1       SUB1          1/9/2015 09:09:09
```

This table records moves from on location/sublocation to another. I don't care about the sublocation.  I just need to report how many days the Asset was at each location. At first I went down this path:

```
SELECT  AssetID,
        LocationID,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(MoveDate), MAX(MoveDate))
FROM    TABLE
GROUP BY AssetID, LocationID
```

However, this quickly revealed a trap, where in the data you can see that the asset moves from LOC1 to LOC2 and back to LOC1. My query would calculate all days for LOC1 between 1/1/2015 and 1/9/2015, when in reality it spent the time betwen 1/5 and 1/9 at LOC99.

Is there a pure SQL way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do this using the LAG window function, but I do not know if it is supported in Azure databases. Otherwise you might have to use a CTE or do some subquerying

Comment: Guys, thanks so much for your help! Unfortunately SQL Azure doesn't have LEAD or LAG functions. The simple join does the trick!!!

Comment: My next challenge will be to figure out how to add a date range answering  the question: For the date range of 1/6/2015-1/8/2015, how many days did the asset stay at each location. I may have to bust out to a stored proc to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor, iterate over the table in date order and build the result set in a temporary table.

It could be done with `LEAD` or `LAG` but they are not available in Azure. Some sort of non-cursor T-SQL solution is no doubt possible, but I doubt the performance would be better than a cursor. A cursor with `FAST_FORWARD` usually performs better than a query containing a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT  [details].[AssetId],
        [details].[LocationId],
        DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([details].[MovedInDate]), [details].[MoveOutDate]) AS DaysIn
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT movedInRow.[AssetId], [movedInRow].[LocationId], [movedInRow].[MoveDate] AS MovedInDate, ISNULL(nm.[MoveDate], GETDATE()) AS MoveOutDate
    FROM [dbo].[t1] movedInRow
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 [MoveDate]
            FROM [dbo].[t1]
            WHERE 
                [AssetId] = movedInRow.[AssetId]
                AND [LocationId] != movedInRow.[LocationId]
                AND [MoveDate] >= [movedInRow].[MoveDate]
                ORDER BY [MoveDate] DESC
        ) nm
) AS details
GROUP BY
    [details].[AssetId],
    [details].[LocationId],
    [details].[MoveOutDate];
```

There might be a possibility that the MoveDate for 2 locations is the same for whatever reason, and this example does not check on that possibility.

```
AssetId LocationId DaysIn
CAR1    LOC1       4
CAR1    LOC1       13
CAR1    LOC99      4
```

Comment: It is. Assuming that the MoveDate column contains a date when the item moved in, then first time it spent 4 days at location LOC1, then 4 days at LOC 99, and then it is still sitting in LOC1 till today (1/22/2015) which is 13 days.

Answer (score 0):

Without using window functions (like LEAD or LAG) and without any t-sql coding you can get it working using **recursive CTE**:

```
/*Create table and sample data*/

create table #mov (
  AssetID varchar(10),
  LocationID varchar(10),
  SublocationID varchar(10),
  MoveDate datetime
)

insert into #mov
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/1/2015 01:01:01' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB2',          '1/3/2015 03:03:03' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/4/2015 04:04:04' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC99',      'SUB99',         '1/5/2015 05:05:05' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB1' ,         '1/9/2015 09:09:09' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/1/2015 01:01:01' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB2',          '1/3/2015 03:03:03' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/4/2015 04:04:04' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC99',      'SUB99',         '1/5/2015 05:05:05' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB1' ,         '1/9/2015 09:09:09'

/*Create CTEs*/
/*1. cteMov - adds the row number to the dataset*/
;with cteMov as (
    select AssetID, LocationID, MoveDate, row_number() over(partition by AssetID order by MoveDate) as rn
    from #mov
),
/*recursive CTE to get records groups*/
rec as (
  select AssetID, LocationID, MoveDate, rn, 1 as rnk
  from cteMov
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select c.AssetID, c.LocationID, c.MoveDate, c.rn, case when c.LocationID = rec.LocationID then rec.rnk else rec.rnk + 1 end as rnk
  from cteMov as c
  join rec on c.AssetID = rec.AssetID and c.rn = rec.rn + 1
)
/*3. Final query*/
select
  rec1.AssetID, rec1.LocationID,
  datediff(dd, min(rec1.MoveDate), isnull(max(rec2.MoveDate), getdate())) as DaysSpent, 
  rec1.rnk
from rec as rec1
left join rec as rec2 on rec1.rnk = rec2.rnk - 1
group by rec1.AssetID, rec1.LocationID, rec1.rnk
order by rec1.AssetID, rec1.rnk
option(MAXRECURSION  0)

/*drop temp table */
drop table #mov
```

Result is:

```
AssetID    LocationID DaysSpent   rnk
---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
CAR1       LOC1       4           1
CAR1       LOC99      4           2
CAR1       LOC1       13          3
CAR2       LOC1       4           1
CAR2       LOC99      4           2
CAR2       LOC1       13          3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sample data from earlier response:

```
create table t1 (
  AssetID varchar(10),
  LocationID varchar(10),
  SublocationID varchar(10),
  MoveDate datetime
);


insert into t1
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/1/2015 01:01:01' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB2',          '1/3/2015 03:03:03' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/4/2015 04:04:04' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC99',      'SUB99',         '1/5/2015 05:05:05' union all
select 'CAR1',    'LOC1',       'SUB1' ,         '1/9/2015 09:09:09' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/1/2015 01:01:01' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB2',          '1/3/2015 03:03:03' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB1',          '1/4/2015 04:04:04' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC99',      'SUB99',         '1/5/2015 05:05:05' union all
select 'CAR2',    'LOC1',       'SUB1' ,         '1/9/2015 09:09:09';

select * from t1;

╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ ASSETID ║ LOCATIONID ║ SUBLOCATIONID ║            MOVEDATE            ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 01 2015 01:01:01+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 01 2015 01:01:01+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB2          ║ January, 03 2015 03:03:03+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB2          ║ January, 03 2015 03:03:03+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 04 2015 04:04:04+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 04 2015 04:04:04+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC99      ║ SUB99         ║ January, 05 2015 05:05:05+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC99      ║ SUB99         ║ January, 05 2015 05:05:05+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 09 2015 09:09:09+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 09 2015 09:09:09+0000 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

If lead() analytic function is supported, then the preferable solution (both in terms of simplicity and performance) would be:

```
select AssetID, LocationID, 
       sum(datediff(dd,MoveDate,isnull(nextMoveDate,getDate()))) daysAtLoc
from (
    select AssetID, LocationID, MoveDate, 
           lead(MoveDate) over (partition by AssetID
                               order by MoveDate) nextMoveDate
    from t1
    ) t2
group by AssetID, LocationID
order by AssetID, LocationID;

╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ASSETID ║ LOCATIONID ║ DAYSATLOC ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║        18 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC99      ║         4 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║        18 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC99      ║         4 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Pure SQL solution: no analytics, no recursive-CTE, no OUTER APPLY/correlated-subqueries; just simple joins.  I've never worked with Azure-SQL, but I'd be pretty amazed if it didn't support this (and still called itself SQL).

```
select AssetID, LocationID, 
       sum(datediff(dd,MoveDate,isnull(nextMoveDate,getdate()))) daysAtLoc
from (
    select  t1.AssetID, LocationID, MoveDate,
            min(nextMoveDate) nextMoveDate
    from    t1 
            left outer join
               (select AssetID, MoveDate nextMoveDate
                from   t1) n
                on t1.AssetId = n.AssetID
                   and MoveDate < nextMoveDate)
    group by t1.AssetID, LocationID, MoveDate
    ) t2
group by AssetID, LocationID
order by AssetID, LocationID


╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ASSETID ║ LOCATIONID ║ DAYSATLOC ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║        18 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC99      ║         4 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║        18 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC99      ║         4 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Performance warning - Let n be the maximum number of moves per asset, and m be the number of assets.  The analytic function version should have Big-O performance of m * (n log n).  The pure-SQL version should have Big-O of m * (n * n).  So if you're tracking a constant pool of assets, but adding more and more moves over time (causing the number of moves per asset to steadily increase), the query will become exponentially slower.  If you're querying over a long time span, and have hundreds or thousands of moves recorded for individual assets, it may be necessary to compute in monthly batches and then sum those results.  That said, if you have a huge pool of assets, and each of them has relatively few moves, the pure-SQL version should perform on-par with Analytic Function version.

-- EDIT 1: Fixed typo on original SQL solution (extra parens)

-- EDIT 2: Expanding solution to support date-ranges - also tweaked input data a bit to verify robustness of solution.

```
create table t1 (
    AssetID varchar(10), 
    LocationID varchar(10), 
    SublocationID varchar(10), 
    MoveDate datetime, 
    primary key (AssetId, MoveDate));

insert into t1
select 'CAR1', 'LOC1',  'SUB1',  '01/01/2015 00:00:00' union 
select 'CAR1', 'LOC1',  'SUB2',  '01/03/2015 03:03:03' union 
select 'CAR1', 'LOC1',  'SUB1',  '01/04/2015 04:04:04' union 
select 'CAR1', 'LOC99', 'SUB99', '01/05/2015 05:05:05' union 
select 'CAR1', 'LOC1',  'SUB1' , '01/09/2015 09:09:09' union 
select 'CAR2', 'LOC1',  'SUB2',  '01/03/2015 03:03:03' union 
select 'CAR2', 'LOC1',  'SUB1',  '01/04/2015 04:04:04' union 
select 'CAR2', 'LOC99', 'SUB99', '01/05/2015 05:05:05' union 
select 'CAR2', 'LOC1',  'SUB1' , '01/09/2015 09:09:09' union 
select 'CAR3', 'LOC2',  'SUB1' , '01/15/2015 15:15:15'
;

╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ ASSETID ║ LOCATIONID ║ SUBLOCATIONID ║            MOVEDATE            ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB2          ║ January, 03 2015 03:03:03+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 04 2015 04:04:04+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC99      ║ SUB99         ║ January, 05 2015 05:05:05+0000 ║
║ CAR1    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 09 2015 09:09:09+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB2          ║ January, 03 2015 03:03:03+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 04 2015 04:04:04+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC99      ║ SUB99         ║ January, 05 2015 05:05:05+0000 ║
║ CAR2    ║ LOC1       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 09 2015 09:09:09+0000 ║
║ CAR3    ║ LOC2       ║ SUB1          ║ January, 15 2015 15:15:15+0000 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

Of course, you don't need to use a table for dt_ranges, I'm just doing so to simultaneously test variety of conditions.  I do prefer to work date ranges in terms of [currentstart,nextstart), as it becomes much easier to write SQL which won't overlap for, e.g. monthly reports.

```
create table dt_range 
    (thisStartDate date, 
     nextStartDate date, 
     primary key (thisStartDate,nextStartDate));

insert into dt_range 
select '01-dec-2014','01-jan-2015' union
select '01-jan-2015','01-feb-2015' union
select '02-jan-2015','09-jan-2015' union
select '01-feb-2015','01-mar-2015' ;

╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ THISSTARTDATE ║ NEXTSTARTDATE ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2014-12-01    ║ 2015-01-01    ║
║ 2015-01-01    ║ 2015-02-01    ║
║ 2015-01-02    ║ 2015-01-09    ║
║ 2015-02-01    ║ 2015-03-01    ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

And the query:

```
select  thisStartDate, nextStartDate, t.AssetID, ArrivalLocation, 
        round(sum(datediff(ss,ArrivalTime, DepartureTime))/(24.0*60*60),1) DaysAtLoc
from (        
select  thisStartDate, nextStartDate, t.AssetID, ArrivalLocation, ArrivalTime, 
        coalesce(min(MoveDate),nextStartDate) DepartureTime
from (
select  assetsInRange.thisStartDate, assetsInRange.nextStartDate, assetsInRange.assetID, 
        coalesce(ArrivalLocation,InitialLocation) ArrivalLocation, 
        coalesce(ArrivalTime,assetsInRange.thisStartDate) ArrivalTime
from 
      (
        select  thisStartDate, nextStartDate, assetID
        from    dt_range
                join t1 on MoveDate < nextStartDate
        group by thisStartDate, nextStartDate, assetID        
      ) assetsInRange
    left outer join
      (
        select  thisStartDate, nextStartDate, assetID, 
                max(MoveDate) precedingDtRangeMoveDt 
        from    dt_range 
                join t1 
                    on MoveDate < thisStartDate
        group by thisStartDate, nextStartDate, assetID
      ) 
      precedingMoveDt
        on (assetsInRange.assetID = precedingMoveDt.assetID)
    left outer join
      (
        select AssetID, MoveDate precedingDtRangeMoveDt, LocationID initialLocation
        from   t1
      ) 
        precedingMoveLoc
        on (precedingMoveDt.assetID = precedingMoveLoc.AssetID
            and precedingMoveDt.precedingDtRangeMoveDt = precedingMoveLoc.precedingDtRangeMoveDt)
    left outer join 
      (
        select AssetId, LocationId ArrivalLocation, MoveDate ArrivalTime
        from t1
      ) 
        arrivals 
        on assetsInRange.AssetID = arrivals.AssetId
                and ArrivalTime >= assetsInRange.thisStartDate
                and ArrivalTime < assetsInRange.nextStartDate
    group by assetsInRange.thisStartDate, assetsInRange.nextStartDate, assetsInRange.AssetId, 
            coalesce(ArrivalLocation,InitialLocation) , 
            coalesce(ArrivalTime,assetsInRange.thisStartDate) 
) t
left join t1 on t.assetID = t1.assetID
            and t1.MoveDate > ArrivalTime
            and t1.MoveDate < nextStartDate
group by thisStartDate, nextStartDate, t.AssetID, ArrivalLocation, ArrivalTime
) t
group by thisStartDate, nextStartDate, t.AssetID, ArrivalLocation
order by 1, 3;
```

And results:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ THISSTARTDATE ║ NEXTSTARTDATE ║ ASSETID ║ ARRIVALLOCATION ║ DAYSATLOC ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2015-01-01    ║ 2015-02-01    ║ CAR1    ║ LOC1            ║ 26.8      ║
║ 2015-01-01    ║ 2015-02-01    ║ CAR1    ║ LOC99           ║ 4.2       ║
║ 2015-01-01    ║ 2015-02-01    ║ CAR2    ║ LOC1            ║ 24.7      ║
║ 2015-01-01    ║ 2015-02-01    ║ CAR2    ║ LOC99           ║ 4.2       ║
║ 2015-01-01    ║ 2015-02-01    ║ CAR3    ║ LOC2            ║ 16.4      ║
║ 2015-01-02    ║ 2015-01-09    ║ CAR1    ║ LOC1            ║ 2.1       ║
║ 2015-01-02    ║ 2015-01-09    ║ CAR1    ║ LOC99           ║ 3.8       ║
║ 2015-01-02    ║ 2015-01-09    ║ CAR2    ║ LOC1            ║ 2.1       ║
║ 2015-01-02    ║ 2015-01-09    ║ CAR2    ║ LOC99           ║ 3.8       ║
║ 2015-02-01    ║ 2015-03-01    ║ CAR1    ║ LOC1            ║ 28        ║
║ 2015-02-01    ║ 2015-03-01    ║ CAR2    ║ LOC1            ║ 28        ║
║ 2015-02-01    ║ 2015-03-01    ║ CAR3    ║ LOC2            ║ 28        ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Note - I assume the first record for an asset indicates it didn't exist at any location previously... so the Dec-2014 - Jan-2015 test month doesn't show up in results as there are no assets with 2014 move dates.

Comment: Love the pure SQL solution. Thanks Alot! Is there a way to modify this to have a date range? So between two dates, where did the asset reside, even if there was no move events during that range...I'm thinking I'm going to have to go stored proc for this... Thanks again!

Comment: Yep - I'll append to main answer to facilitate formatting.